# Programmatically selecting NSToolBarItem

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

How can I programmatically select an NSToolbar item?

```
[toolbar setSelectedItemIdentifier:[theToolbarItem itemIdentifier]]
```

This code only selects it.  I want to send it's action too, so that it changes panes.

Comment: bLacK hoLE's answer would be my way around it too. The issue here is that the toolbar is just a view and the controller should implement the code responsible for the various items on it. In your case I would call the action method for whatever you're selecting right beneath your supplied code.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the target and action of the NSButton in the nib file itself, or if you need to do it programmatically, then create an IBOutlet to the NSButton and do it in code.

When you use an NSButton in a toolbar item, it effectively acts like an NSButton would anywhere else in your interface, rather than as an NSToolbarItem per se. For example, you won't be able to easily disable or enable the button through the use of the standard -validateToolbarItem: or -validateUserInterfaceItem:; rather, you'll need to have an IBOutlet to the button in question, or otherwise use bindings to enable or disable the button.